# Magento 2 knockout js in checkout page

Tags: magento2, javascript, template, knockoutjs

I want to customize checkout page but i am confused about calling template with knockout js. In `Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml` there is a script like this:

```
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#checkout": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
    }
}
</script>
```

What is the meaning of this script?

Comment: Welcome to Magento StackExchange :). What exactly you want to achieve? Please explain in question

Comment: Hi @AnkitShah i want to know where is html file that called by knockout js

Comment: `magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js`

Comment: @AnkitShah I am not understand, that file contains js file.

Comment: U r finding `<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>` where this is coming from? `magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Block\Onepage.php` `public function getJsLayout()`

Answer (score 10):

**TL:DR**

The template it calls is `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html`.

My research is below.

### What does this script do?

```
"#checkout": {
    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
}
```

This informs Magento to call the JS layout if the `#checkout` element exists on the page.

---

```
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
```

The above code tells Magento to render a template, now how does it know which template to render? If you look at the parent `div` you'll see this code:

```
data-bind="scope:'checkout'"
```

This is informing Magento that the nested code is in relation of the checkout (it does more than this but I'm not going too far into it).

---

### Find the template

The template **can** be defined within the `text/x-magento-init` tag, but Magento don't usually do it this way as you can see. Magento usually do it via the XML method, which is what this line does:

```
$block->getJsLayout();
```

This gets the components configuration from the XML, so let's take a look at that.

---

If you search `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout` for `onepage.phtml` it should return `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`. So let's look in here for the config.

Nested within `checkout.root` you will see a lot of `<argument>` tags, if you look at this line - `<item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">` this relates to the scope we saw earlier. Within this there is a line that defines a template:

```
<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/onepage</item>
```

So this means the getTemplate() call is returning:

```
magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html
```

As you can tell by the XML file UI components can be pretty overwhelming, there is also a lot more that I've left out it could go on forever and I don't have a good understanding of all aspects yet. But hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To call a JS component on a HTML element without direct access to the element or with no relation to a certain element, Magento use the  tag.

See
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html for more details